# Consumir funcion Web Service WSDL con Nusoap PHP

Tags: php, html

alguien me prodia ayudar , soy nuevo en php y estoy  tratando de consumir un servicio por el protocolo soap  y no he podido llamar la función que contiene un array con un listado para cargarlo a un combobox . si alguien me prodria ayudar se lo agradecería.

```
 $respuesta = $client->__soapCall('alumnos', array('id' => '01','Nombre' => 'Esteban'));
    print_r($respuesta);
```

Comment: No sé si te ayude, pero para mejorar tu código puedes guardar los argumentos del arreglo de la llamada en una variable: 
$parametros = array('id' => '01','Nombre' => 'Esteban'); 
$client->__soapCall('alumnos', array('$parametros));

Comment: Que error te marca?, ya iniciaste el servicio de la varable `$client` ?